# passing any data type / object as parameter to determine it's size

Tags: c++, c

I'm pretty sure I already have the answer to my question in C, but unsure for Cpp.

```
typedef struct strXXX {
    uint16_t member1;
    uint8_t member2;
    // ...
} XXX;

XXX tst;

void some_init_func(void * obj, uint16_t sz)
{
    obj = &tst;
    size = sz;
}
```

when calling *some_init_func*, size has to be given with:

```
sizeof(tst)
```

Is there a way to pass any object or data type to *some_init_func*, and determine the size of the object in the function?

I do think it's not possible in C/Cpp as you can pass a pointer, but can't determine the size of the object itself from it's pointer,
but I'd like to know if some of you hard coders have found a workaround about this lack in these languages?

...other than this kind of macro (which won't do the trick all the time as size parameter may not be right after object address):

```
#define PASS_OBJ(obj)    &obj, sizeof(obj)
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++ you could just use a template function:

```
template <typename T> void some_init_func(T* obj)
{
    const size_t size = sizeof(T);

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Just for my understanding: This solution requires that the caller knows the exact type of the object to be passed, and the solution cannot deal with polymorphism, right?

Comment: Yes, you're right about the limitations - the OP seemed to just be asking about initialising POD types though (presumably you'd never do something this nasty with actual objects, I would hope), so I think it's a reasonable solution in that context.

Comment: it's reasonable enough, this would just be to pass a data type with fixed size, without polymorphism. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: You may so add `static_assert(!std::is_class<T>::value || !std::is_polymorphic<T>::value, "!");` to avoid to bypass the limitation.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that it's possible especially because of the [padding of data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment#Data_structure_padding) that is present in C/C++. `sizeof()` is there for a reason.

In C++ you can convert your function to a template function. This will enforce passing the type whenever you call it. You can than use `sizeof()` inside the function to calculate the size of the passed object of that type.

Answer (score 0):

Basicly, it is impossible to get the object size when it is passing as `void *` type, cause the object type can be implicitely converted to any object you wish.

However, if to speak about C++ - abstract class is the solution:

```
class Template {
public:
  virtual void method1()=0;
  virtual void method2(void *)=0;
};
```

In this case, you can pass not `void *` type object but `Template *` derived object, where `method2` can take common `void *` parameter with later implementation and conversion it to needed object type with known size.